# How to prove set containments on power sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$P(A-B) \not =P(A) - P(B)$

How can we apply here the definition of a power set?

$P(A)=\{S|S \text{ is a subset of }A\}$

$P(B)=\{S|S \text{ is a subset of }B\}$

$P(A-B)=\{S|S \text{ is a subset of }A \text{ and not of } B \}$

Comment: The definition of A-B is wrong.  It should say something like $P(A-B)=\{S|S \subseteq A-B\}.$

Comment: I observe that you *never* learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17543/290189).  You may want to try a WYSIWYG [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) so that you math is typed as what you intend to mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously True if $A \cap B \not= \emptyset$. In case that $A \cap B = \emptyset $, $P(A-B)=P(A)-P(B).$

Also, $ \emptyset \in P(A-B)$ unless $A-B = \emptyset$, but $\emptyset \not\in P(A)−P(B)$ and that is because - $\emptyset \in P(A),P(B)$ (unless $P(A)=P(B) = \emptyset)$.

A more accurate definition of $P(A-B)$ might be $\{S\,|\,\forall s\in S:s\in A \,\land s\not\in B\}$.

Comment: There is no "unless", as definitely $\emptyset\in \mathcal P(\emptyset)$ , because, $\mathcal P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$

Answer (score 1):

The set constructors you require are:

$\begin{align}
\mathcal P(A)\smallsetminus\mathcal P(B)
   & =\{S\mid S\in\mathcal P(A)\wedge S\notin \mathcal P(B)\}
 & \textsf{definition of set difference}
\\ &=\{S\mid S\subseteq A\wedge S\nsubseteq B\}\tag 1
 & \textsf{definition of power set}
\\ &=\{S\mid (\forall x\in S.x\in A)\wedge(\exists x\in S.x\notin B)\}
 & \textsf{definition of subset(or equal)}
\\[2ex]
\mathcal P(A\smallsetminus B)
   & =\{S\mid S \subseteq (A \smallsetminus B) \}\tag 2
 & \textsf{definition of power set}
\\ & =\{S\mid \forall x\in S. x\in (A\smallsetminus B)\}
 & \textsf{definition of subset(or equal)}
\\ &= \{S\mid \forall x\in S. (x\in A\wedge x\notin B)\}
 & \textsf{definition of set difference}
\\ &= \{S\mid (\forall x\in S.x\in A)\wedge(\forall x\in S.x\notin B)\}
 & \textsf{quantifier distribution}
\end{align}$

---

Of note, $\emptyset \subseteq A$, $\emptyset \subseteq B$, and $\emptyset \subseteq (A\smallsetminus B)$, therefore ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. Then $A-B=\{1\}$ and 
$$P(A)=\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{2\}, \{1,2\}\}, \qquad P(B)=\{\emptyset,\{2\}\}$$ 
Now compare the sets.

Answer (score 0):

$A = \{1,2,3\}$

$B = \{1,2\}$

$A-B = \{3\}$

$\{1,3\}$ is the example you need.

Answer (score 0):

yYur definition of $P(A \setminus B)$ is wrong. Let's take $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}^+$ as an example.

$\mathbb{N} \setminus \mathbb{N}^+ = \{0\}$

As such, it's power set will be $\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$. Following your definition of $P(A \setminus B)$, it will contain any set which has a zero in it.